# Path search library in C++ for looking through list of paths for file

Tags: c++, hash, filepath

I'm working on an open source circuit simulator. Circuit schematics can contain subcircuits which are in their own files. Just before simulation of a circuit, it is 'flattened' in a preprocessing stage, to a single file. Currently subcircuits must be referenced by their full path in the schematic. I would like to allow users supply just the name of the circuit, and have the simulator search a list of paths for the appropriate file in a similar way to a compiler, or similarly look up the file from a pre-searched stored list of files.

How can I implement such a search using the C++ Qt framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a QMap or std::map for mapping the circuit names to the circuits. Then, it is just simply the matter of a lookup, like:

```
myCircuitPath = myQMap.value(myCircuitName);
```

or

```
myCircuitPath = myStdMap.at(myCiruitName);
```

For anything more serious, you will need to start learning C++ more in depth, or show us your code, and we can help extending it...

Comment: Thanks, that is a good starting point, if you are interested the code it is the Qucs circuit simulator: http://sourceforge.net/projects/qucs/